# TikZ: odd behaviour when fading

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have a rectangular filled domain and need to fade when moving away toward the left and bottom. I'm running into problems with the fadings where they meet. Here's my MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\fill[red] (1,1) rectangle (2,2);
\fill[red,path fading=west] (1,1) -- (1,2) -- (0,2) -- (0,0) -- (1,1); 
\fill[red,path fading=south] (1,1) -- (0,0) -- (2,0) -- (2,1) -- (1,1); 

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The output is:

[image]

There seem to be two problems:

1. The fading seems to be inconsistent near the diagonal (darker red than when moving vertically or horizontally away from the diagonal).
2. There is a very thin white diagonal line, see the following figure (zoomed in).

[image]

How I can get rid of or work around these problems?

Comment: The white line is a viewer issue. According to what I find when the output is viewed with `acroread`, there is no such white line.

Comment: @Schrödinger's cat: Good point, but I get the same behavior no matter whether I use Apple Preview, Skim or Adobe Reader.

Comment: Interesting. I get it only on preview. (One can improve it quite a bit using `\clip`s.)

Comment: You mean by shading the corner region twice and using the clip to remove the twice-drawn bits?

Comment: No, `\begin{tikzpicture}
\fill[red] (1,1) rectangle (2,2);
\begin{scope}
\clip (1,1) |- (0,2) -- (0,0) -- cycle; 
\fill[red,path fading=west] (0,0) rectangle (1,2);
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}
\clip (1,1) -- (0,0) -| (2,1) -- cycle; 
\fill[red,path fading=south] (0,0) rectangle (2,1);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}` looks better on my viewers, but does not avoid the problem of the darker region at the diagonal.

Comment: Indeed, this looks better along the diagonal. Is the first problem a bug?

Comment: I do not think it is a bug in the strict sense but just the way how the viewers implement the fading. It is known that fading and shading are "vulnerable" in that these features are not produced by Ti*k*Z but by the viewers. For instance, on p. 364 of pgfmanual v3.1.5 you can find "Not all renderers, let alone printers, will support this. At the time of writing, Apple’s Preview will
not show the following correctly ...", and there are more statements in that direction.

Comment: Hm. If you add an answer based on your comment(s), I'll accept it, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is by no means a complete answer but some suggestions of how you can improve the output on some viewers. One suggestion is to use clip, and another one is to change the fading in the lower left quadrant.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\fill[red] (1,1) rectangle (2,2);
\begin{scope}
\clip (1,1) |- (0,2) -- (0,0) -- cycle; 
\fill[red,path fading=west] (0,0) rectangle (1,2);
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}
\clip (1,1) -- (0,0) -| (2,1) -- cycle; 
\fill[red,path fading=south] (0,0) rectangle (2,1);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}


\tikzfading[name=fade out,inner color=transparent!0,outer color=transparent!100]
\begin{tikzpicture}
\fill[red] (1,1) rectangle (2,2);
\begin{scope}
\clip (0,1) rectangle (1,2); 
\fill[red,path fading=west] (0,0) rectangle (1,2);
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}
\clip (1,0)  rectangle (2,1); 
\fill[red,path fading=south] (0,0) rectangle (2,1);
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}
\clip (0,0)  rectangle (1,1); 
\fill[red,path fading=fade out] (0,0) rectangle (2,2);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

When I zoom into the second picture with preview on MacOS, I get

[image]

However, at different zoom levels some very faint white lines show up

[image]

Ironically, these are red lines in Acrobat reader at the same magnification (300%).

[image]

The pgf manual mentions these viewer issues at various places.

I'd advise you not to accept the answer prematurely. Maybe someone else has a more complete or even true solution.